# How do I kill a dragon critically?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there locational damage (e.g: headshots) in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34936/is-there-locational-damage-e-g-headshots-in-skyrim)
>   [What are Dragons most vulnerable to?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35489/what-are-dragons-most-vulnerable-to)

Is there such a thing as a dragon's weak spot, which I could hit to quickly kill it?

Comment: Yeah what's there weak spot?

Answer (score 4):

No creature in Skyrim has any weak or strong spots, shooting somebody in the foot is as effective as shooting them in the head.

That said, dragons are least dangerous when you keep to their side, as their wing attacks are weaker and they can't use their breath attack on you that way.