# Does where I aim my attack matter in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I attack someone in Skyrim does it make a difference where I hit the person i mean it doesn't seem like it does because I shot a guy three time in the head with a bow and he was still alive and trying to kill me.

Comment: Hi John, and welcome to Arqade! I think you'll find the answer you're looking for [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34936/is-there-locational-damage-e-g-headshots-in-skyrim).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: there are mods that can add in location based damage if you are interested in things like that for the pc

Comment: @spartacus that would make a good answer to that other question.