# How to clear this jump in Egypt - Obelisk of Khamoon

Tags: tomb-raider-anniversary

How do you clear the below jump in the Tomb Raider Anniversary level **Egypt - Obelisk of Khamoon**?

[A visual tutorial](http://tomb-raider-anniversary.com/tomb-raider-anniversary-walkthrough/Level10_Obelisk_Khamoon/index4.php) on tomb-raider-anniversary.com implies that you should just jump straight at the ledge, but I've tried it about 50 times with no luck.

What happens is that she stretches one arm out, and appears to be reaching for the long platform on the left, but hits the protruding edge on the right with her body, falls straight down and dies.

I also tried different timings with Lara's movement before she jumps. None seem to have any positive effect.

[image: Screenshot of Laura before jumping, with an arrow pointing out the trajectory]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It appears there are [a number of people](https://steamcommunity.com/app/8000/discussions/0/882965239738031019/) who encountered the same issue.

Possible reported solutions include:

- Changing the aspect ratio
- Using manual grab
- Changing anti aliasing
- Reinstalling the game

After a bit of tweaking with the screen resolution, I was able to make the jump.

In my case, I was using a 4:3 aspect ratio. I changed it to 16:9 (1920 x 1080), retried the jump and succeeded.

Comment: As a software developer, two hands for facepalm is just not enough...

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's not a bug, it's an unlisted feature. It could be part of a puzzle. Lara finds an ancient scroll that reads "Thou must change your aspect ratio if you do wish to succeed the jump"

Comment: How in the sam hill does screen resolution in a 3D game affect gameplay physics?! @PlasmaHH you can borrow my hands for that facepalm.

Comment: My guess (as a former games developer) would be that they decided to use the camera to inform the movement of the character, presumable so Lara appears to move in the correct plane for the viewer, and the camera angle shifts when you change the aspect ratio making the jump impossible.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I would imagine that if you were one of the developers of the game in question then you would have zero issues glitching yourself three or sixteen hands to facepalm with.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: just that unless the chair you sit in has the right proportions, you grab your own ass with them

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I created an account here just to upvote your comment

Comment: @Ap31 [Same here! :-)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34936/is-there-locational-damage-e-g-headshots-in-skyrim/39437#comment268753_39437)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus wow the circle is now complete. I used to jump ledges at 4:3 aspect ratio, but then I took an arrow to the knee...

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me this option (PC version), found in a Forum discussing Ledge Bug in "Oblesik of Khamoon" where Lara keeps falling down colliding a left side corner as in above Picture of Tomb Raider-Anniversary. To resolve it you need to enable V-Sync, How to enable is this ------> From Steam game library click play, don't choose first top option of play game yet, choose other option of game Tomb raider: Anniversary setup, click play now, it will open a setup window, where in bottom 6 checkbox options are Clickable, one of them is "Enbale V-Sync" Click / check yes, this box. then start playing game. Damn corner where i fell down about 40 times.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I enabled v-sync in steam setup options before you start the game. It did work for me when I played without v-sync checked.