# Bug: Pressing E, but cannot pry window open

Tags: thief

I noticed this bug for the side-mission "Check, Mate", which involves breaking into Archie Maxwell's house in Mourningside.

I'm prompted to hold E if I want to open the window, and then to tap E repeatedly to pry it open, but it won't finish no matter how much I tap it. This means the side mission cannot be completed, and you have to reload an earlier save.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a bug in the PC version, where your **monitor refresh rate** sometimes has improper effects on the gameplay. In my case, I had it set to 120hz.

Make sure your Display settings are set to 60hz and try again, and you should be able to pry the window open normally.

Comment: Not [the first time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286056/how-to-clear-this-jump-in-egypt-obelisk-of-khamoon) that a computer monitor was the culprit of a "bug."

Comment: The strange/unpredictable part is that it's just *one* point (perhaps the only one in the game?) that shows symptoms, so it can pop up long after the changes seem stable.